# How can I get resized text size after setting longer text to AppCompatTextView in android

Tags: android, textview, font-size

Currently, I get wrong text size of AppCompatTextView after I set text longer than width?

XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
     <!--mTextView1-->
     <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="30sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:maxWidth="55dp"
            android:text="80"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
        <!--mTextView2-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/textview2"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="30sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:maxWidth="55dp"
            android:text="1009.22"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
     </LinearLayout>
```

Activity code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private AppCompatTextView mTextView1;
        private AppCompatTextView mTextView2;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
              mTextView1 = findViewById(R.id.textview1);
              mTextView2 = findViewById(R.id.textview2);

              mTextView1.setText("80");
              Log.d("zzz" , "textview1 getTextSize " + mTextView1.getTextSize() / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity);

              mTextView2.setText("1009.22");
              Log.d("zzz" , "textview2 getTextSize " + mTextView2.getTextSize() / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity);
        }
}
```

Logcat:

```
 02-01 09:27:50.307 3680-3680/com.example.zzz.testproject D/zzz: textview1 getTextSize 30.0
 02-01 09:27:50.307 3680-3680/com.example.zzz.testproject D/zzz: textview2 getTextSize 30.0
```

Images:
[image]

So my question is how can I get scale textsize of mTextView2 correctly? Please help to take a look. Thanks!

Comment: How do you mean *"auto resize text"* instead of *"default size"*? Do you mean to say you want pixel size or dp or sp?

Comment: What do you mean by auto-resize? You can set the text size programmatically from java. There is now way that a system will know that you want certain text in different size. You have to write code for that.

Comment: @Abbas please take a look, I've updated question.

Comment: I don't think you've made it any clearer. Using the same words in the image is not really helpful. Try some other words which convey the same meaning. Or further elaborate what you mean.

Comment: It looks like it's impossible.